# I have some problem with a reactive table in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a dashboard using shiny in R, but I'm facing some little problems

I have:

`db` is my `data.frame` with:

```
db$domain:chr, 
db$date:chr,
db$value:num.
```

So I've created:

```
db_4 <- reactive({ subset(db,db$domain %in% input$domain &
db$date<=input$daterange[2] & db$date>=input$daterange[1]})
```

the inputs are:

```
input$domain: selectinput with multiple choices,
input$date: daterangeinput.
```

I'm trying to create a table that gives me the sum of the db$value, aggregated by db$date. I've tried something like:

```
output$table2 <- rendertable ({aggregate(db_4()["value"], by=list(db_4()["date"]), sum) })
```

but I get always an empty table.

Can anybody help me in solving this little issue?

Thx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend you to read [this article](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205612627-Debugging-with-RStudio) about debugging.

In Shiny you can use the `browser()` function within both `reactive` and `render` functions. It should help you locate the problem (i.e.: data has the expected structure)

It seems the problem is with the `aggregate` function: `db_4()["date"]` returns a `data.frame`, where you need a vector.

### Solution:

```
library(shiny)

db <- data.frame(
  domain = letters[1:3],
  date = seq(
    from = as.Date("2019-01-01"),
    to = as.Date("2019-06-01"),
    by = "1 months"
  ),
  value = runif(12)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("domain", "Domain", choices = unique(db$domain)),
      dateRangeInput("daterange", "Date", 
                     min = min(db$date), max = max(db$date),
                     start = min(db$date), end = max(db$date))  
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table2")      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  db_4 <- reactive( { 
    subset(db, 
      db$domain %in% input$domain &
      db$date<=input$daterange[2] & 
      db$date>=input$daterange[1]
    )
  })

  output$table2 <- renderTable( {
    req(db_4()) # Don't render table when db_4() is NULL

    # Uncomment next line to check if everything goes as expected
    #browser()
    aggregate(
      data.frame(value = db_4()$value), 
      by=list(date = as.factor(db_4()$date)), 
      sum
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Also I would highly recommend sharing the code of your minimal example including some dummy data, so that it can be copy-pasted in an instant. It would increase the chances of someone answering.